# protobuf embedded message best practice

Tags: c++, protocol-buffers

I have a protobuf message that contains another repeating message. It looks like this:

```
message AddGroupsRequest
{
    message GroupProperties
    {
        string name = 1;
        int32 some_property_1 = 2;
        int32 some_property_2 = 3;
    }

    repeated GroupProperties group_properties = 1;
}
```

My question is whether that's the best way to encode the messages, or should they be separated like this:

```
message GroupProperties
{
    string name = 1;
    int32 some_property_1 = 2;
    int32 some_property_2 = 3;
}

message AddGroupsRequest
{
    repeated GroupProperties group_properties = 1;
}
```

Are there implications for defining the message one way or another?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The underlying encoding of the two specifications will be identical when using the binary output.

```
$> echo 'group_properties { name: "Bob", some_property_1: 6 }' \
      | protoc nested.proto --encode='AddGroupsRequest'        \
      | xxd

00000000: 0a07 0a03 426f 6210 06                   ....Bob..
```

```
$> echo 'group_properties { name: "Bob", some_property_1: 6 }' \
      | protoc sibling.proto --encode='AddGroupsRequest'       \
      | xxd

00000000: 0a07 0a03 426f 6210 06                   ....Bob..
```

The only decision point is if you want the generated C++ class name to be `AddGroupsRequest_GroupProperties` (in nested form) or if you want an independent `GroupProperties` type, which is largely a preference thing. Note that you can change this later without breaking the already-encoded messages.

Comment: Thanks @travis - I like the fact that it could be changed later without breaking. I think the encoded name format "outer_inner" is messy in the generated C++, but I think it's more informative in the .proto language. Decisions... Did you generate the encoding with some tool - if so, what was it?

Comment: If I understand what you're asking, the tool is `protoc`. The `--encode` and `--decode` flags are poorly-documented ways to create and decode messages of a given type right from the command line. You should be able to copy and paste those examples (assuming you have the proper `sibling.proto` file there).